# Is it possible to force set a value in ValidForm Builder?

Tags: validform

I have 2 sets of radio buttons. Is it possible in [ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org) to set one instance of radio buttons to a certain value based on a conditional check against the other radio button?

```
  // Radio List #1
  $objRB1 = $objForm->addField('rb1', 'Radio Button #1', VFORM_RADIO_LIST,
    array(),
    array(),
    array('default' => $default['rb1'])
  );
  $objRB1->addField('Red', 'R');
  $objRB1->addField('Green', 'G');
  $objRB1->addField('Blue', 'B');

  // Radio List #2 -- NEED TO FORCE SET THIS TO "Delta" WHENEVER "Blue" IS SELECTED ABOVE
  $objRB2 = $objForm->addField('rb2', 'Radio Button #2', VFORM_RADIO_LIST,
    array(),
    array(),
    array('default' => $default['rb2'])
  );
  $objRB2->addField('Alpha', 'A');
  $objRB2->addField('Delta', 'D');
  $objRB2->addField('Omega', 'O');
```

How might that be done, if possible, in VFB?

Answer (score 0):

#### ValidForm Builder conditions

ValidForm Builder has three conditions:

1. Visible
2. Enabled
3. Required

These three settings you can influence with conditions at the moment. Conditions don't change (default) values.

#### Workaround

A workaround would be to create two fields: one with value A as default value and one with value B as default value.

Then, you use a condition to trigger the visibility of both fields. When, on a third field, option A is chosen, only field A is visible with default value A. When option B is chosen, field B is shown (with the exact same label and values) but with value B as default value.

However, when implementing such a workaround, make sure you **don't** name field A and B exactly the same. Field names should always be unique.